# How to hook into Angular's request animation frame

Tags: angular, requestanimationframe

We're currently using request animation frame for custom animations but it appears Angular is also using request animation frame for change detection. We now have two back to back function calls based on animation frame fired which effectively duplicates .onLeave call stack. Any Angular experts can offer some guidance?